# Cut the line in div elements

Tags: html

Is there a way to remove lining for "ddd" below. I mean i need line only for 'Sev'

```
<div class = "container" style = "padding-left:10px"><h4  style = "border-bottom-style:solid;width:fit-content">Sev ddd</h4></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```html
<div class = "container" style = "padding-left:10px">

<h4>
  <span style = "border-bottom-style:solid;width:fit-content">
   Sev
  </span>
 ddd
</h4>
  
</div>
```